# Ruby on rails git push heroku master issue with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

i know this is an old issue and i saw many questions related to the same issue. I still keep getting the same error. I followed the solutions and changed my gemfile accordingly but i still get the same issue. Im using ubuntu. 
Below is my issue when i run git push heroku master as said in Michael Hartl's tutorial:

```
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_t7ck4nq1x4dd/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_t7ck4nq1x4dd/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:pure-dusk-8885.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pure-dusk-8885.git'
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :production do 
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'taps'
  gem 'rvm'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ryan Bigg said you should have the same environment in both development and production so you don't have surprises later when you deploy to production.

But if you don't care about that and want to keep with sqlite I think you only need to run `bundle install`. I guess you changed your GemFile but didn't ran bundle install.

Comment: i ran bundle install, removed the sqlite3 gem, committed it to git, but still im getting the same error :(

Comment: yes, i deleted that one too, after running bundle install there was gemfile.lock, i removed the gemfile.lock so that the dependencies on sqlite3 might me removed, and then ran git push heroku master, and i still get the same, is it because the i already created the first_app and database.yml is having the sqlite3 format?

Comment: Hi i followed these steps as mentioned in some post in SO "bundle install
git add .
git commit -am "Added PG to Gemfile"
git push heroku master" but i still could not run. I'm not having access to my laptop anyway right now. I will try it today evening creating a rails app afresh and following the suggestions mentioned here. I will reply back here if it does not work. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove sqlite3 from your Gemfile. Develop using only the `pg` gem, so that you're developing on exactly the same database system as what you're deploying to.

If you're not doing this, then you may run into problems when you transition between the two database systems.